How to properly declare ResourceBundle in Quarkus Native build? (MyFaces Extension)
I'm trying to load a Java's class as Resource bundle in faces-config.xml:
<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>app.LanguageBundle</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>

The class is annotated with @RegisterForReflection, but it seems this is not enough to load it.
I'm getting the following error
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name app.LanguageBundle, locale de_DE
    at java.base@21.0.5/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2059)
    at java.base@21.0.5/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1697)
    at java.base@21.0.5/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1600)
    at java.base@21.0.5/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1283)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.getResourceBundle(ApplicationImpl.java:417)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.getResourceBundle(ApplicationImpl.java:381)
    at jakarta.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.getResourceBundle(ApplicationWrapper.java:263)
    at jakarta.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.getResourceBundle(ApplicationWrapper.java:263)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.resolver.ResourceBundleResolver.getResourceBundle(ResourceBundleResolver.java:212)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.resolver.ResourceBundleResolver.getValue(ResourceBundleResolver.java:132)
    at jakarta.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:136)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:100)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:238)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:45)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:46)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:362)

I have found this reference in registering Java class as resource Bundle, but I don't know how to use it withing an app, not an extension.
Update 19.11.2024:
The properties are stored somewhere else and not in *.properties files. To use them, I create a class like
@RegisterForReflection
public class LanguageBundle extends ResourceBundle {

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        // whatever
    }
}

And then load it as mentioned before. Somehow it can't be found in the native build.

Yes so you can see in our Quarkus Faces demo app: https://github.com/melloware/quarkus-faces
The bundle goes in src/main/resources/: https://github.com/melloware/quarkus-faces/blob/main/src/main/resources/build.properties
And its referenced in faces-config.xml: https://github.com/melloware/quarkus-faces/blob/efd3fd4f3a8de6ab83f1bd0ce93d0f3345e7659e/src/main/resources/META-INF/faces-config.xml#L38-L41
<resource-bundle>
  <base-name>build</base-name>
  <var>build</var>
</resource-bundle>

If its failing in Native GraalVM mode don't forget to include your properties in application.properties to make sure they are included in the Native image.
quarkus.native.resources.includes=*.properties

You can see our running Faces application running in GraalVM native mode here: https://quarkus-faces-melloware-8a6a34c1.koyeb.app/index.xhtml

Thank you @Melloware! Of course, I followed your projects :)
I was able to make it work that way, however, it was also required to add quarkus.native.additional-build-args=-H:IncludeResourceBundles=i18n.messages.
The problem I still have and the one I tried to describe in this issue, I can't make it work for a bundle that is not a *.properties files, but a class that extends ResourceBundle. I tried all possible ways I guess, but no success.
If you have time to debug, I can provide a simple reproducer.

Hmmm ResourceBundles are treated special in Quarkus so you may have to live with that.  See what I have to do in the PF Extension to include all its bundles: https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-primefaces/blob/413ed29aede8cf6bb55880a06d4151744888f041/quarkus-primefaces/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkiverse/primefaces/deployment/PrimeFacesProcessor.java#L95-L118
